# Hide div if facebook comments are 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I'm using Facebook social plugin and everything works fine. I want to hide the div of my "chat bubble"

[image: chat bubble]

if

```
<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="[article URL]"></span>
```

is zero for each article loaded on my homepage and ofcourse keep the not zero ones.
Also additional information, I'm using a "show more" button to load other articles using ajax as well.

I already tried using http://graph.facebook.com/ to get the information whether the address contains comments and it worked, but because I needed to ping http://graph.facebook.com/ for each article, my page loading times was abysmal so I removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function iterate over span having "fb-comments-count" class. And find if the text of this span is zero or not. If it's zero, get the parent of this class(Article DIV) and hide the bubble DIV using hide() method.

https://api.jquery.com/each/
`//for iterating .fb-comments-count`

http://api.jquery.com/text/
`//for getting get count from span`

https://api.jquery.com/parent/
`//to get the parent DIV by class or ID of span`

http://api.jquery.com/hide/
`//to hide the perticular div by class or ID.`

> Call this function every time you fetch the articles using AJAX.

e.g.

```
function yourCustomFunction() {
    $('span.fb-comments-count').each(function(index) {
         var count=$(this).text();
         if(count==0) {
              var parentDiv=$(this).parent('article.yourParentDivClass');

              parentDiv.find('.bubbleDiv').hide();
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but will there be an issue because it takes a certain time to load the facebook comments count after the page loads?

Comment: Call this function only after facebook comments are loaded. There should be callback function for success. After that it will handle the rest.

Comment: The JS SDK has [events you can subscribe to](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5), one of them is called `xfbml.render`, and fires when all social plugins on the page are loaded. (I am not totally sure if that works for `fb-comments-count` as well, but I think it should.)

Answer (score 0):

The span is given the class 'fb_comments_count_zero' if there are no comments, so you can set that class to be display:none in your styleshet

Comment: I saw that answer and I tried it, but it doen't do that anymore it seems. When I inspect the element after loading the zero it still says class="'fb_comments_count". I still tried putting display:none; in my css file for the 'fb_comments_count_zero' class but it didn't do anything.

Comment: You can also use like below:
`if($(".fb-comments-count").text() == "0"){
$(".fb-comments-count").hide();
}`

Comment: I used the combination of your answer and the one other one to make a solution. I still needed to subscribe to the facebook render event because i used ajax to load more articles on my page and the div i was looking for to hide wasn't the comments one, but a div few layers above. But instead of using a for loop to search for the spans that are 0 value, I used the class fb_comments_count_zero.